# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method is not invoked in OSX App

Tags: swift, macos, push-notification

I'm developing a MacOS app and trying to registering for Push notifications using the below code.

```
    func initPushNotification() {
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, _ in
            guard granted else { return }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                NSApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
    }
```

But the below methods are never called.

```
    func application(_ application: NSApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let token = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
        print("APNs token retrieved: \(token)")
    }
    
    func application(_ application: NSApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Failed to register")
    }
```

Note:
I have added Push notifications under capabilities and calling the `initPushNotifications()` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method
When the above method is called, the OS shows a notification banner asking the user to grant permissions. Upon granting, `NSApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()` gets called but none of the callback delegate methods are invoked.